# How to properly add data to AWS amplify DynamoDb from a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, aws-amplify

I setup a project with Amplify flutter and I need to add data to my DynamoDB from a Lambda function. The function actually adds the data to the DynamoDb when I run it and I can see the data in the DynamoDb section of the AWS management console but the issue lies in how to display this data in my Amplify flutter project. When I query the table, I only see the data I added directly from the Amplify flutter app. It seems I'm not properly adding the data from my Lambda function, here's the function below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),


mydocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    var params = {
        Item : {
            id :  '12345',
             "senderID" : "test",
             "recieverID" : "test",
             "message" : "test",
        },
        TableName : 'Chat-hdwvylbm45a23azaykzyshblu4-staging'
    }
    
    mydocumentClient.put(params, function(err, data){
        callback(err, data);
    })
}
```

Below is code to query the database.

```
Future<void> read() async {
    try {
      List<Chat> chatItems = await Amplify.DataStore.query(Chat.classType);
      setState(() {
        randomExcerciseData = chatItems;
      });
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('Query failed: $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: `I only see the data I added directly from the Amplify flutter app` - well where is your code to get data from DynamoDB? What is the expected output? What is your actual problem?

Comment: I'll update my question to show the code to get data from DynamoDb, the expected output is to be able to see the data that is added to the Dynamodb through the lamda function, al i see is the data i entered via the emulator running my Amplify flutter project.

Comment: But you said `The function actually adds the data to the DynamoDb when I run it and I can see the data in the DynamoDb section of the AWS management console` ?

Comment: The lambda function succesfully adds the data to the DynamodB, the problem is that when i query the DB from my emulator running the app linked to the DB, i don't see the added data. I only see the data i added directly through the Abdroid emulator running the app

Comment: So can you see the data or not via the emulator? You're saying you don't see it and then you say `I only see the data i added directly through the Abdroid emulator`

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with the Lambda - if the data is there in the database, it's there. The issue is that your Flutter application can't read data from DDB - correct? If so, I'd get rid of the Lambda code and add a screenshot of the data being in the table along with the result of the query. Is it behaviour only relating to the emulator or does it do the same on a physical device?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, apparently there was no problem with my code, i just had to uninstall and reinstall the app, everything is ok now.

Comment: Wonderful :) glad you got it sorted